# Infinite loop when redirecting output to the input file

Tags: bash

I have a csv file that I loop through and pick only some lines. Like that:

```
while read p; do
    if [[ "$p" =~ '0'$ ]]; then
        echo "$p"
    fi
done <$1
```

I would like the picked records to be appended to the original file, like this

- old_records
- "Picked records:"
- new_appended_record

However, when I add `>> $1` at the end of my script I seem to enter into an infinite loop.

Comment: Reading from a file as you modify it (in this case, appending to it) can cause a lot of trouble if you don't understand how the writing & reading interact. It's much safer to save the selected lines somewhere else temporarily, then append them only after you finish scanning the file's original contents.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Do you mean something like this:
-read loop
->write to temp file
->append temp_file to the input_file
->remove temp_file
?
And, will the loop at the top of the script not read the values appended from the temp file? Or maybe I need to do something to make it break before the joining of the temp file? Thank you

Comment: Yes, something like that. As long as you put the "append" step *after the end of the read loop*, it won't read the new lines you append (because it'll have finished reading already).

Comment: BTW, you could also replace the `while read` loop with something like `grep '0$' "$1" >"$tmpfile"`

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #13 (cat file | sed s/foo/bar/ > file)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file).